# Stripe API - Retrieve Info On Multiple Charges Using One Call

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently using the [retrieve()](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve) method to retrieve multiple charges one by one in a loop.  We have a page on our app that allows a user to see the status of all payments that he is entitled to.  This page takes quite a bit of time to load since we are sometimes calling `\Stripe\Charge::retrieve()` dozens of times in a row.

Is there anyway for me to make one call where I pass in an array of charge IDs and get info back on multiple charges from the same call?  I see there is a list charges method at https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list, but this method doesn't allow me to pass in a list of charge IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there's no way to make batch retrieval requests. However considering that you are trying to retrieve charges for a single user, you can still use the list API method and pass in the customer ID: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list#list_charges-customer

Then once you have the list (probably time constrained via other [properties in the list call](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list#list_charges-created)) you can filter through and return the status of each.